# How do I use LLDB to debug a raw i386 MBR binary running in QEMU, on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Tags: qemu, lldb, bootloader

I'm working on an i386 bootloader and I'm running it with QEMU on my Apple Silicon machine, and everything works just fine, except I can't debug it: GDB does not (yet?) work on AS and LLDB sternly refuses to load a raw binary. This starts up fine:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -s -S -drive format=raw,file=boot.bin,media=disk,if=floppy -no-fd-bootchk
```

but this errors out:

```
$ lldb boot.bin
(lldb) target create "boot.bin"
error: '/Users/morpheu5/src/boots/cube/boot.bin' doesn't contain the architecture x86_64
```

and I also tried this, because well, it's supposed to be i386, not x86_64:

```
$ lldb --arch i386 boot.bin
(lldb) target create --arch=i386 "boot.bin"
error: '/Users/morpheu5/src/boots/cube/boot.bin' doesn't contain the architecture i386
```

but it didn't make much of a difference. The inline help is not greatly helpful and I am having zero success searching online.

Now, I have alternatives: bochs has an internal debugger but the text-based interface is a bit clunky and I can't even figure out how to pre-set certain breakpoints -- I like to break on 0x7c00 or otherwise I have to step through the entire BIOS code -- and I can't even run the gui debugger despite having configured it with `display_library: sdl2, options=gui_debug`. The other alternative is a Raspberry Pi in which I could probably use gdb but I haven't tried this out yet and it's a Zero so it's not even that powerful anyway -- not that I need it, but I'd rather keep my workflow smooth...

It seems clear that lldb isn't recognizing the binary's format so I'm wondering if there's a way of just asking it to disassemble it as a 32 bit binary and just roll with it the best it can. In the end, all I really need is a way of seeing what is in memory, in the registers, and in the stack.

Any ideas?

Comment: I dunno whether lldb works well with QEMU's gdbstub anyway -- mostly people use it with gdb. You shouldn't need a gdb that knows about Apple Silicon specifically as a target, you just want it to be built on an Apple Silicon host and with support for (at least) the i386 target.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that gdb doesn't even build on Apple Silicon.

Comment: It sounds like this isn't an object file format that lldb recognizes.  lldb does work with the qemu gdb protocol stub, but that isn't your problem. Your session is failing at a earlier stage because you can't get lldb to read in the object file correctly.  What is the format of this binary file?

Comment: @JimIngham it's a raw binary, meant to be written in the first sector of a floppy disk, like it says at the top of the question. I understand that lldb is unable to guess the file format, I am wondering if there's a way of telling it to shut up and just disassemble it.

Comment: No, lldb only reads in files whose format it understands, and it doesn't have a "bare bits, no sections, no symbols" object file reader.  That wouldn't be particularly hard to add but no-one's needed it.   lldb also wants to know about the OS its connecting to, so you'd probably have to monkey with that part of lldb to make it work as well.

Comment: You could file an ER for this support with the lldb bug tracker, but I haven't seen interest expressed in this debugging scenario in lldb from other quarters, so you might not get any takers.

Comment: Alright, it's good to hear for sure that lldb won't be of help – not in the immediate anyway. It looks like I'm not having much joy from gdb on Linux either, but that's a different matter.

Comment: In lldb you could try making an empty target, with just an architecture and no file.  You can't do that from command-line lldb but you can run `target = lldb.debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch(None, "i386"); lldb.debugger.SetSelectedTarget(target)`.  Then attach to the qemu stub: `(lldb) gdb-remote localhost:portNumber`.  That might work or at least mostly, depending on how upset lldb gets at not understanding anything about the system it is attached to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few weeks of experimentation, it doesn't look like lldb is a viable option, but Bochs' command-line debugger was somewhat useful. Shame I couldn't get the GUI to run on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install x86_64-elf-gdb
qemu-system-i386 -s -S result.bin
x86_64-elf-gdb -ex "target remote localhost:1234" -ex "set architecture i8086" -ex "set disassembly-flavor intel" ····
```

this works for me, but this don't use lldb.